# Improving Server-side Datatable performance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, datatables

I am using datatables in my rails app and the load times are beginning to slow down now that there are about 16,000 records in the table. I have configured the table to process data server-side and use the will_paginate gem but the load times are still often around 5 seconds. Anything in particular amiss with my code below that would cause for these long load times?

Note - I commented a few lines in the code snippets below to see if it made a difference in load times - it did not.

Thank you!
-Mike

```
class AccountsDatatable
  delegate :params, :h, :link_to, :number_to_currency, to: :@view
  attr_reader :user
  include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
  include Pundit

  def pundit_user
    User.find(@current_user_id)
  end

  def initialize(view, account_status, current_user_id)
    @view = view
    @account_status = account_status
    @current_user_id = current_user_id
    @current_user = User.find(current_user_id)
  end

  def as_json(options = {})
    {
      sEcho: params[:sEcho].to_i,
      iTotalRecords: Account.count,
      iTotalDisplayRecords: accounts.total_entries,
      aaData: data
    }
  end

  private
  def data
    accounts.map do |account|
      [
        account.account_name,
        account.account_status.to_s.humanize,
        #account.get_departments_with_active_opportunities,
        #account.get_departments_with_active_lobs,
        link_to("Open", account_path(account), class: "btn btn-xs btn-success"),
        ((policy(account).update?) ? link_to("Edit", edit_modal_form_accounts_path(id: account.id), class: "btn btn-xs btn-default", remote: true) : "&nbsp;"),
        ((policy(account).destroy?) ? link_to("Delete", delete_modal_form_accounts_path(id: account.id), class: "btn btn-xs btn-danger", remote: true) : "&nbsp;")
      ]
    end
  end

  def accounts
    @accounts ||= fetch_accounts
  end

  def fetch_accounts
    if @account_status.nil? || @account_status == "all"
      accounts = Account.order("#{sort_column} #{sort_direction}").all
    else
      accounts = Account.order("#{sort_column} #{sort_direction}").where(account_status: @account_status)
    end
    if params[:sSearch].present?
      search = params[:sSearch]
      begin
        accounts = accounts.or( { account_name: (/.*#{search}.*/i) } )
      rescue
        accounts = accounts.or( { account_name: (/^#{::Regexp.escape(search)}$/i) } )
      end
    end
    accounts = accounts.paginate(:page => page, :per_page => per_page)
    accounts
  end

  def page
    params[:iDisplayStart].to_i/per_page + 1
  end

  def per_page
    params[:iDisplayLength].to_i > 0 ? params[:iDisplayLength].to_i : 10
  end

  def sort_column
    columns = %w[account_name account_status] 
    columns[params[:iSortCol_0].to_i] 
  end

  def sort_direction
    params[:sSortDir_0] == "desc" ? "desc" : "asc"
  end

end
```

Page Script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    const datatable_options = { 
      sPaginationType: 'full_numbers',
      bProcessing: true,
      bServerSide: true,
      sAjaxSource: $('#accounts_table').data('source'),
      columns: [
        null,
        null,
        // { orderable: false },
        // { orderable: false },
        { orderable: false },
        { orderable: false },
        { orderable: false }
      ]
    };
    initialize_datatable('#accounts_table', datatable_options);
  });
```

View

```
<table id = "accounts_table" class="table table-striped accounts_table" data-source="<%= accounts_path(format: "json", account_status: @account_status ) %>" >
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Account Name</th>
              <th>Classification</th>
              <!--<th>Active prospecting departments</th>-->
              <!--<th>Active departments</th>-->
              <th>&nbsp;</th>
              <th>&nbsp;</th>
              <th>&nbsp;</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
          </tbody>
        </table>
```

Comment: how fast your database can run a query will depend on the indexing - did you created and run migrations to index your table by account_name?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at: [DataTables is running slow. How can I speed it up?](https://datatables.net/faqs/#speed)

> **Q. DataTables is running slow. How can I speed it up?**
>   A. There are several ways in which you can speed up DataTables. Often the first
>   thing to do is enable paging
>   ([`paging`](//datatables.net/reference/option/paging)) if it has been
>   disabled as this simply reduces the amount of data to be displayed.
>   Beyond that, the method you are using for loading the data will
>   typically have the most significant impact on performance.
>
> - Client-side processing - DOM sourced data: ~5'000 rows. Speed options:
>     [`orderClasses`](//datatables.net/reference/option/orderClasses).
> - Client-side processing - Ajax sourced data ([`ajax`](//datatables.net/reference/option/ajax)): ~50'000 rows.
>     Speed options:
>     [`deferRender`](//datatables.net/reference/option/deferRender)
> - Server-side processing ([`serverSide`](//datatables.net/reference/option/serverSide)):
>     millions of rows.

The numbers above are just a guidance. The actual numbers and the impact on performance depend on various factors like Browser version, plugins, etc.